# Roles in login not being stored in User of security context

Tags: symfony, authentication, orm, doctrine

After searching for 2 days and trying many different solutions I couldn't find the answer. I have followed the steps of a tutorial (http://roberto.costumero.es/2011/08/15/creando-un-login-simple-con-symfony2/) to build a simple login process where I have:

- Table for User
- Table for Role

Many to many relation between them (user_rol). All the mysql tables were correctly created and i have the ORM Doctrine Classes also.

If I load a user by hand and load their roles it works perfectly fine but when I use this automatic login

```
{% block body %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Usuario:</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="_password" />

    {#
    If you want to control the URL the user
    is redirected to on success (more details below)
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After login in the user is identified but there is a warning message in the _profiler saying "Authenticated NO" (probably because the user has no roles)

So I do this in the code:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
print_r(count($user->getRoles()))
```

And the roles are empty. Any ideas?

P.D: I tried overwriting the serialize function of the object and including the roles but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few questions:

1. Does your User entity extends the Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User class?
2. Does your getRoles() return an array with a string for each role?

Maybe you need to force in the constructor to set the roles in the user, because if you are using another entity to manage roles, what you haver are Role objects, not an array of strings identifying the roles.

Comment: By the way, the article you follow is from 2011, and maybe is using Symfony 2.0, I think you must read the official documentation for your version (latest I guess) http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form 
Symfony have a really good documentation.

Comment: 1. It implements the following Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface 2. yes I modified that function to return an array with a string for each role.